# Missing CGLProfiler.h on Mac OSX 1.9

Tags: macos, opengl

I am trying to use the OpenGL Profiler on Mac OSX 1.9 (Maverick) programatically as described in manual. However my /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers is missing the CGLProfiler.h and CGLProfilerFunctionEnum.h files. All other files seems to be there (OpenGL applcations are compiling/working without problem).

I have installed the latest version command-line tools like suggested in one of the answers but it did not change anything. The OpenGL profiler by itself is working fine. Any idea where I can find the missing files?

Comment: Headers are not usually stored in that directory. They should be relative to the OS X platform SDK, which Xcode installs into a different path. I cannot tell you the exact path off the top of my head, since Apple keeps changing the way Xcode structures the filesystem. I know it used to be `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/`, now I believe it is contained within the `Xcode.app` package (which seems silly to me, as it makes browsing the file system needlessly complicated from Finder).

Comment: I looked inside the XCode.app (Xcode 5)  and did not find anything. In manual examples `<OpenGL/CGLProfiler.h>` is included which should be `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers`. This directory on my Mac contains all(?) other files except those two.

Comment: I'm also missing these files on OS X 10.10. Looked at the API documentation but it looked like the files should still be there according to it. Tried installing the command line tools to no avail.